# Database copy on Datacenter

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have an application running on AWS Cloud.
We have a local datacenter in Switzerland.
We want to maintain a copy of the full application with database(Mysql RDS instance) deployed on AWS, on our local datacenter.

The local datacenter has a dedicated server with VMware standard license. I couldn't figure out what would be the the best solution

```
Option 1: AWS datasync + Localservers 
Option 2: Aws datasync + AWs Snowcone (instead of using localservers)
Option 3: AWS direct connect
```

We don't want real-time sync but a sync every 2-3 hours is good enough. Which strategy is best for us?

We just want to keep a copy of our data on our servers

Comment: And your question is? How to get the qualification to ask a question? Because you tel a lot what you want to do - you totally fail to ask a specific question. "Do my work for me" is NOT a question.

Comment: @TomTom you totally fail to ask a explain what is wrong with my question.

Comment: A question would be something like "given the scenario described above, what is the best way to copy our AWS based resources back to our data center". TomTom has a point, but it's fairly obvious what you're asking, even if you don't explicitly state it.

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably get better help if you explained why you wanted to do this. Is it for HA, for DR, or just because it seems like a good idea to have a copy of your data? I trust AWS, but I also like to have a copy of my data outside AWS.

A good approach for you could be to replicate to a MySQL server running outside of AWS, [as per this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html). This is not quite real time, but it's close, and it's probably easier to set up than a periodic backup.

Another option for MySQL is to allow your datacentre based server to access the server, with "allow public access" but using security groups to limit it to your server. Just have your server run any MySQL backup tool you like.

If you also want to back up files there are many ways. You could

- Run RSync
- Run backup software that stores to a repo in S3, then sync from S3 to your data center (restic could work)
- Backup from your AWS server to S3 and not bother to copy to your data center.

Personally I do a MySQL dump every night, and backup that dump and the server files using Restic to S3, then replicate from S3 to a server using "aws s3 sync" command line.

Comment: Just a naive question, How do you get to  know that the dumps are not corrupted, i.e somethings happens on a day and your data dumps will all be corrupted from that day.

I can write scripts to do that, relatively easy to do but amazon provides solutions now a days in which we can sync my on-premise MySQL instance with MySQL instance on AWS cloud.

Comment: You should schedule regular restore / DR tests. The dumps I do are nothing to do with AWS, it's an EC2 instance running a MySQL command line tool. If you want to replicate MySQL RDS to outside RDS that's also fine, RDS lets you do that, but AFAIK doesn't provide anything to make it easier - it's standard MySQL replication.